# Перевод из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную и наоборот

Tags: c

Мне нужно ввести десятичное число, и программа должна:
 1)перевести его в двоичную, потом переделать это бинарный код  заменив 1 на 0 и 0 на 1 и вывести этот бинарный код
 2) Потом этот уже новый бинарный код перевести в число.
1-вое задание у меня получилось сделать в функции DecToBin и вывел его в main 
А 2-рое Не получилось,делал я его в функции BinToDec и пытался вывести в main 
Помогите пожалуйста

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void DecToBin(int num, int bin){
for (int i=16;i>=0;i--){
    int bin2;
    bin2=num>>i;
    if(bin2&1)printf("0");
    else printf("1");
    }
    }
void BinToDec(int num, int bin){
        int num2,bin2,i;
        num2=num;
        num2=bin2>>i;
        printf("%d",num);
        }


    int main(){
        int num,bin;
        printf("Your number:");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        printf("In binary:",num);
        DecToBin(num,bin);
        printf("\n");
        printf("In number:",num);
        BinToDec(num,bin);
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: зачем в каждой функции аргумент bin, если он не используется?

Comment: Остался с прошлых попыток, что я только с кодом не делал

Comment: А всего-навсего стоило один раз выполнить код построчно под отладчиком...

Comment: Не понял, как это построчно под отладчиком ?

Comment: Есть такая волшебная штука - отладчик (ака дебаггер) который позволяет выполнять код строчка за строчкой и показывает текущие значения переменных. А еще имеет смыл читать предупреждения компилятора.

Comment: Впервые слышу про отладчик